# Entity Framework 6 - Many to Many Foreign Key Constraint Causing Multiple Cascade Paths Error

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api, cascading-deletes

I have a many to many relationship defined as follows:

```
public class Ticket 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public ICollection<ApplicationUser> TicketSubscribers { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
     public ICollection<Ticket> SubscriberTickets { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent api mappings as follows:

```
 public ApplicationUserConfiguration()
 {
       HasMany<Ticket>(u => u.SubscriberTickets)
       .WithMany(t => t.TicketSubscribers)
       .Map(
           ts =>
           {
               ts.MapLeftKey("UserId");
               ts.MapRightKey("TicketId");
               ts.ToTable("TicketSubscriber");
           });
 }
```

Migration is as follows:

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.TicketSubscriber",
            c => new
                {
                    UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    TicketId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.TicketId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.User", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Ticket", t => t.TicketId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.UserId)
            .Index(t => t.TicketId);
```

When I run update database I get the following error:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.TicketSubscriber_dbo.Ticket_TicketId' on table 'TicketSubscriber' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

I dont know how you can specify cascade delete false on a many to many mapping?

Why would it generate this error on a many to many mapping. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try the InverseProperty attribute  http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx